# Kiel traduki la vorton „Done!“ en programo?

Tags: translation

Kiam komputilaj programoj faras ion, kaj kiam tiu io bezonas tempon por kompletiĝi, je la fino la programoj foje montrus la vorton:

> *Done!*

Kiel traduki tion al Esperanto? Kompreneble, tiu vorto devus esti parto el pli longa frazo, sed kia frazo? (Por ke oni povu elekti la ĝustan vorton el tio.) Jen kelkaj ideoj:

> *Ĉio estas farita!* — do ni povus mallongigi ĉi tion al → *Farita!*
>
> *Ĉio esats preta/pretigita!* → *Preta!* aŭ *Pretigita!*
>
> *La proceso/ago finiĝis!* → *Finiĝis!*
>
> *La proceso/ago estas finita!* → *Finita!*

Kion oni elektu? (Kiam la spaco estas limigita.)

Answer (score 3):

*Finita*, *finiĝis*, aŭ *farita* estas bona vorto.

Ĉi tiu bildo estas el Edukado. Ĝi diris la vorton '*farita*' post kiam oni faris teston.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Laŭ mia sento „Preta!” plej ofte taŭgas.

Answer (score 1):

Estas mirige, ke neniu ĝisnuna respondinto sentis bezonon de adverba finaĵo. Memoru, el la *Proverbaro Esperanta* (n-ro 843, alfabete 361):

**Dirite, farite!<sup>Z</sup>**

Tiaj adverboj estas oftegaj en la ĉiutaga Esperanto, speciale *farite!* ĉe la fino de taskoj, aŭ *komprenite!* post ricevo de instrukcioj aŭ klarigoj, aŭ *interkonsentite!*... la listo estas longa.

Ĉu oni komprenas tiajn formojn kiel perverbajn priskribojn de subkomprenataj *ke*-subfrazoj (*estas interkonsentite, ke ni faru tion*), ĉu kiel perverbajn priskribojn en sensubjektaj frazoj (*estas farite!*), ili bezonas e-finaĵon ([PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/participoj/e-vortoj.html#i-goj)).

Vere, adjektivo eblas nur, kiam eblas apliki ĝin al substantivo. Do, *rezulto: farita* funkcias, ĉar temas pri farita *testo*. Do, se vi printus

**Tasko farita**

mi ne kontraŭus. Tamen, simpla angla *done!* tradukiĝas per *farite!*

Ho, nun ke mi pensas pri tio, al koncizemulo sufiĉus tutsimpla *ite!* ...

Answer (score 0):

Farita! estas bone laŭ mi, kaj bone iras kun aliaj oftaj samkuntekstaj utilaj vortoj:

- "faranta" (work in progress)
- "farenda" (*to do*)
- "farinda" (mi konas nenion idiotisman Anglan ekvivalento).

Ankaŭ anstataŭ "DONE", foje estas uzita "OK" kaj "KO", depende de la rezulto, kiu sukcesis aŭ malsukscsis. Por tio oni povas uzi ekzemple "BONE" kaj "MISE".